# Pinescript How to plot indicator with multiple timeframe conditions

Tags: pine-script

In Pine script i have multiple rules with different conditions that needs to work on different timeframe. So for example, Rule 1 & 2 will work between 10:15 to 14:15, If the condition is true during the said timeframe they will plot buy signal. If rule 1 and rule 2 do not satisfy the condition till 14:15, it will show buy signal as per the condition defined in Rule 3.

Now below code, always validate the first 1 hr closing candle and do not wait till 14:15 candle close for rule 3.

```
//New Bar

is_newbar(res, sess) =>
    t = time(res, sess)
    na(t[1]) and not na(t) or t[1] > t


openingBarClosed = is_newbar(pivotTF, session.regular)[1]
openingBarOpen = is_newbar(pivotTF, session.regular)
```

Comment: I assume you are trying this on the 1h timeframe. Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I am actually using the script from here:https://www.tradingview.com/script/d0R4THit-CPR-Option-Selling-Strategy/ This works on 1hr first candle closing. However, for IC rule, i want it should evaluate at 14:15 candle and not at closing of 9:15 candle. So the system should keep evaluating the rule CE and PE till 14:15 and if it is not met, then at 14:15 it should apply IC rule